# How can I share a printer in Windows over a MiFi router?

Tags: printing, network-printer, mifi

We're running an event in a couple of weeks and will need to set up a small ad hoc office. We're planning on using a MiFi for our light internet use (mostly email and updating the event's website). If possible we'd also like to share access to a printer attached to a Windows PC via USB.

From what I've read normal Windows network sharing won't work with a MiFi router. Are there any ways round this?

I've had a quick look at Google Cloud Print but it doesn't look like it supports printing from anything other than Chrome, and even that's with a restricted set of document types.

Of course it wouldn't the be the end of the world if we had to pass around a USB flash drive, but it would be nice to have a network based solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the standard Windows sharing. It should work with any local area network including the one created by your MiFi device.

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't think this would work.